# How can I show the data with comma(,) in drop down box on window?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have written the program to show all the data on window but stuck in the case for showi a single record with comma(,) in drop down box. Let me share codes what i tried.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt_seq_report
FIELD npai_output_expression    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(50)".

/* Followings are written inside the drop down box using progress app builder */ 
/* ON VALUE CHANGED      OF   coCombo-4    Part Type(Label Name) */                               
DO:

  DEFINE VARIABLE cPartTyp AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
  CREATE tt_seq_report.
  ASSIGN 
  tt_seq_report.npai_attribute_expression = "22+++,56-".

  coCombo-4:ADD-LAST(tt_seq_report.npai_attribute_expression).

END.
```

When I run the window and select the drop down box then i can see the value upto before comma(,) i.e 22+++ but it should show the full value like 22+++,56-.    May I get any help regarding this?

Comment: Your sample code does not compile and is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the combo-box'es DELIMITER property to any other character. Comma is just a default.

"Delimiter character can have any ASCII value from 1 to 127. The default delimiter is a comma."

Comment: How can i do that? could you pls share some screen shot with color marked?..bcs in property sheet i can see delimiter is disabled and cannot edit that